# How can I export THESE 2 matrices in one excel file with proper spacing and formatting in Rstudio

Tags: r, excel, matrix, export

Truck location coordinates>

```
  X[Now] Y[Now]
A    5.4   15.4
B    8.3    9.0
C    6.6    5.2
D    6.5   13.5
E   15.0    1.9
```

Load location coordinates> print(Bcd)

```
   Pick-up-X Pick-up-Y Drop-off-X Drop-off-Y
1       18.3       0.5        4.0       13.9
2       11.1       0.1       17.1       18.9
3       20.0       8.9       18.4        7.4
4        4.4      18.2        8.6       15.0
5       12.7       2.9        4.0        0.7
6        5.2      10.7       16.9       18.9
7       18.5      19.0        4.8        9.5
8        8.2      17.3        0.6        4.6
9       11.5       0.5        3.4       11.4
10       2.1      11.3       11.4        0.1
```

Comment: I think many people would prefer to export as 2 csv's. Or perhaps copy to clipboard and pasting into Excel. Something like `write.table(matrix1, 'clipboard', sep='\t')`

Comment: Have you had a look at the `openxlsx` package? There are other packages which may help but I am not familiar with them such as: `writexl`